# Cookies are not stored in browser in live environment using Express as Backend and REACT as Front End on Digitalocean App Platform

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

My cookies are not saved in the React front end (issued by express backend) after deploying it to digitalocean as App.

We have spent days searching the entire stack overflow site and google but can’t explain why our cookies are saved properly on local host but not on our dev environment, which deployed through digital ocean.

We can see the cookie in the response header but it just won’t save in the browsers storage - neither chrome nor safari.

Backend

```
app.post('/api/cookie', function (req, res) {
    //Base this on refresh token and make sure it is in hours
    const userCookieAge = '1';

    function setCookieAge(req) {
        let hours = req
        let age =  hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        return age
    }

    const AuthCookieSettings =  {
        domain: process.env.COOKIES_DOMAIN,
        maxAge: setCookieAge(userCookieAge),
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 'none' : 'lax',
    }
    
    
    const UserCookieSettings = {
        domain: process.env.COOKIES_DOMAIN,
        maxAge: setCookieAge(userCookieAge),
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none'
    }

    let key = req.body.key
    let value = req.body.value

    // Creates Secure Cookie with refresh token
    res
    .cookie( 'auth-cookie', JSON.stringify({ [key]: value,Settings: AuthCookieSettings}), AuthCookieSettings)
    .cookie( 'user-cookie', JSON.stringify({ [key]: value,Settings:UserCookieSettings}), UserCookieSettings)
   
    .json({status: 'succss', message: `Successfully created two cookies with key ${key} and value ${value}`});

});
```

PROCESS ENV

```
COOKIES_DOMAIN=".ondigitalocean.app"
```

CORS Settings

```
const allowedOrigins = require('./allowedOrigins');

const corsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
        console.log(`Request from Origin ${origin}`)
        if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
            console.log(`CORS request for Origin ${origin} granted`)
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error(`CORS request for Origin ${origin} denied!`));

        }
    },
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    allowedHeaders: [
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credential",
        "Origin",
        "withCredentials",
        "X-Requested-With",
        "Content-Type",
        "Accept",
        "Authorization",
        "X-HTTP-Method-Override",
        "Set-Cookie",
        "Cookie",
        "Request"
    ],
}

module.exports = corsOptions;
```

Frontend

```
 const [ key, setKey ] = useState('')
  const [ value, setValue ] = useState('')
  const url = '/api/cookie'

  async function getCookie() {
    const payload = {
      key,
      value
    };

    console.log(JSON.stringify(payload))
    
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(url,
        JSON.stringify(payload),
        {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            withCredentials: true
        }
      );
      
      const data = response?.data

      if (data) {
        console.log(`Response ${data.status}`)
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)     
    }
   
  }
```

Beside some code snippets, you may you find a small test setup under

Front end: https://dev-frontend-f2yv7.ondigitalocean.app/
Back End: https://sea-lion-app-rm8kh.ondigitalocean.app/

A test procedure of the cookie front & backend can be found under
https://dev-frontend-f2yv7.ondigitalocean.app/account/test

Simply type in key and value and click the get cookie button.

I would really appreciate your help on this as I got no idea what I a doing wrong.

Thank you
Mat

Comment: What is the value of process.env.COOKIES_DOMAIN ??

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me @JRichardsz and sorry that i missed thay part. I just updated it - the domain value is ".ondigitalocean.app"

Answer (score 0):

for anyone facing the same issue with the DigitalOcean App Service.  The real problem are not the cookie settings, but the domain settings. You must use your own custom domain name in their App Service to make cookies work. In my case I used a subdomain for the backend e.g. server.intutec.io and the regular domain for the front end intutec.io

I hope that helps...